# LaTeX - Portable Editing Environment

Tags: editors, distributions

I have a TeX document which I want to edit and make sure it's rendered correctly.
Which means I need an Editor with Preview window.

I searched over the Internet.
There's too much info and I can't get it right.
I use Windows 7 64 Bit.

I would like to avoid any installation of a program.
Is there a Portable Editor which includes all needed libraries in it and allow Preview of the TeX file?

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count. This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Have you tried [writeLaTeX](https://www.writelatex.com) ? It is a free online LaTeX editor with integrated rapid preview.

It compiles automatically for you as you type, there is no need to install anything, and no need to sign up (unless you choose to to manage your documents).

(I should point out that I'm one of the developers of writeLaTeX - we hope you find it useful, and any feedback is appreciated, thanks)

Comment: I'm adding the option "ShaerLatex" at https://www.sharelatex.com/.

Answer (score 7):

By 'portable' I assume you mean on a memory stick. There are lots of editors that will work like that, but without a TeX system you are not going to get very far. So perhaps you start by looking at [portable MiKTeX](http://www.miktex.org/portable/about), which includes the [TeXworks editor](http://tug.org/texworks/). The later includes previewing in PDF mode.

Comment: If I'm using Portable MiKTeX, Could I use other editors? Which one would you recommend?

Comment: For a portable viewer, you could use http://portableapps.com/apps/office/sumatra_pdf_portable

Comment: Quite a lot of editors can be used portably, by the way. I've used WinEdt that way in the past, but I think TeXniccenter can also be used portably. I'd suggest telling us which editor you prefer, and we can make a suggestion.

Comment: Since those are my first steps in the TeX world I don't have any preference. I'm here to learn from the experienced users. Given I downloaded MiKTeX portable, How do Integrate an Editor to use it? Thank You.

Comment: As I said, the TeXworks editor is part of Portable MiKTeX. As it shown here: http://www.miktex.org/portable/about, you should be able to start TeXworks in portable mode using the MiKTeX portable system.

Comment: [Portable Miktex is 32-bit only](http://www.miktex.org/portable), so it would not meet the OP's requirements.

Comment: @HarryMacpherson Yes it would: 64-bit Windows will happily run 32-bit programs, and there's not really any benefit using 64 bits for TeX.

Answer (score 2):

When portable MiKTeX is mentioned, also [TeX live](http://www.tug.org/texlive/) and its portable installation, http://www.tug.org/texlive/doc/texlive-en/texlive-en.html#tlportable, should be noted, which also both include the TeXworks editor.

Answer (score 1):

The [TexMaker](http://www.xm1math.net/texmaker/download.html) editor "feels" a lot like Kile (but cleaner) and has portable versions available for download at the link provided ;)

Answer (score 0):

I think there are two (Online) solutions should be mentioned:

https://www.writelatex.com/

https://www.sharelatex.com/

This is as portable as you get (Assuming Internet connection).

Comment: One of these just copies the [answer above](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/94592/) which you said was great (but failed to accept) months ago!