# portable LaTeX on thumbdrive

Tags: portability

What is the most common solution to getting TeX on the go.

I am looking for a way to fit everything onto a thumbdrive. (up to 8Gb?)

It needs to be able to have a text editor and a typesetting system. I tried installing my student-license WinEdt onto a thumbdrive and use [MikTeX portable](http://www.miktex.org/portable), but this is not compiling things properly.

I assume that the typeset system is one of the best available, so assuming that I get the system setup correctly, what other text editors would you recommend?

P.S. some systems I work on do no have acrobat. (ie. pdf not supported)

Comment: For editors, see [LaTeX Editors/IDEs](http://goo.gl/3f1mL). Both MiKTeX and TeX Live come in portable forms; see [Portable editing environment](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/4814/5764). Without know what the problem is with your compiling, its hard to go much further.

Comment: If you add [SumatraPDF](http://blog.kowalczyk.info/software/sumatrapdf/download-free-pdf-viewer.html) to what @Werner suggested above, you have a working portable LeTeX system. I'm assuming you're using Windows...

Comment: You should try [proTeXt](http://portableapps.com/node/34534) . It's a one click install of portable MiKTeX and TeXStudio bundled.

Comment: What operating system are we talking about? MikTex Portable is pre-compiled for Windows OS.

Comment: I've marked as a dupe: there are several possibles, depending on exact requirements!